# Can anyone tell me why my code is failing to create a database and table, and then store data in them.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, cllocationmanager

So my code is suppose to create a database and table, and then store my location data in the table. It's hitting all the right logs that I made, like "Created Table" and "Location inserted", but when I go to find the file it's either (a) not there or (b) there but has no location data in it.

I started off using CoreData, but it quickly turned into a nightmare so I changed to using sqlite directly.

```
        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        locationManager.delegate = self; 
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 



// Create a string containing the full path to the bold2.db inside the documents folder
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bold2.sql"];

    // Check to see if the database file already exists
    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // Open the database and store the handle as a data member
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databasehandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Create the database if it doesn't yet exists in the file system
        if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
        {
            // Create the LOCATION table
            const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOCATION (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, timeStamp DATE)";
            char *error;
            if (sqlite3_exec(databasehandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
          {
                NSLog(@"Created Table");
                 }
              }
```

Here is the location delegate where I'm getting a new location and inserting it into the database. The weird thing is that it actually hits the "Location inserted" log.

```
    -(void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *) manager
    didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *) newLocation
           fromLocation: (CLLocation *) oldLocation
{

    NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO location (latitude, longitude, timeStamp) VALUES (%g, %g, %g)",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude, newLocation.timestamp];    
    char *error;   
    if ( sqlite3_exec(databasehandle, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Location inserted. %g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    }    

    else NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
}
```

Comment: When you say "when I go to find the file" what do you mean?  Are you running this on the simulator or a device? And does the "Created Table" message get logged on every invocation of the program?  I'm not sure but I think the simulator may not retain files between runs.

Comment: Print the paths of your database on simulator and devices.

Comment: I'm running it on the simulator. The "created table" gets logged whenever I change the name of the sql file, thus making it create a new one. If the file is already there, it just goes straight to "Location Inserted". I'm not getting any error messages either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Since I'm remoting into a minimac the file path to the db was hidden. I just pasted the correct filepath in go to folder and found the right file.